# Preventing windows from going over the top of the screen (in win XP)

Tags: windows, macos, mac, gui

These days I work on both Windows and Mac OS X machines. I'm a long time fan of Mac and would like to get some of the UI functionality on the windows machines I work with.

In OSX the menubar is the hard limit for windows, and I like that. Is there a way - some hack, some program or anything - to prevent windows from going up OVER the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Pitaschio**](http://pitaschio.ara3.net/)  can do this, and much much more:

> - Snap a window to other windows when moving and resizing
> - **Restrict a window position to inside of the screen**
> - Always keep a window above all other windows
> - Minimize a window to the system tray
> - Use small icons in the desktop
> - Disable Windows key, Insert key, Alt key etc.
> - Lock the mouse or keyboard while cleaning them
> - Take statistics about mouse and keyboard
> - Calculate Moon's age
> - Control the sound volume using the mouse wheel
> - Display the sound volume level on the screen

[image]

Pitaschio is freeware.

If you only want the top of the screen to be a boundary, you can use [AutoHotkey's](http://autohotkey.com) functions [WinGetPos](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinGetPos.htm) and [WinMove](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinMove.htm).

To get the position of the active window, and store it in the variables X and Y:

```
WinGetPos, X, Y, , , A
```

if the window you're moving goes out of the top boundary (negative value for Y), call WinMove:

```
WinGetTitle, Title, A ; get its title
WinMove, %Title% , , %X%, 0 ; leave X value alone, modify Y
```

Comment: Don't count on that autohotkey trick working if your system has multiple monitors that aren't aligned on their top edges. Depending on the exact settings, you can get 0 being out of view on the vertically smaller monitor. (I've got a laptop with external monitor, hence the size difference. I keep the tops unaligned so that I have small 'step' between the monitors at the top and bottom instead of a large 'step' at the bottom. I find this makes it less likely that I'll get the mouse 'hung up' on the step and lose track of where it is.)

Comment: You are correct! By how the question was worded I assumed he was using 1 monitor. But you can also do bounds checking in AHK. Check if the windows position is past a certain X value (on the second screen) and if it is, and the window goes above the **different** Y value, move it back down. Pitaschio is much easier than wrapping your head around code though.

Answer (score 1):

Is the problem that you can't move the window because the draggable window header is inaccessible?  If that's the case, you can move the window back down by right-clicking on the app in the task bar, selecting move, and then using the cursor keys to move the window back down.

Answer (score 0):

[**DesktopCoral**](http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Mouser/desktopcoral/index.html) can do this. You can set an invisible docking bar in any corner on the screen.

[image]